# How to mock getenv in pytest?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

In some of my test, I need to mock some function calls such as os.getenv, I tried to combine mock.patch but I guess pytest and patch don't go hand in hand, how can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't bother with `mock.patch`.  Since you are using `pytest`, you should use the fixture [mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html#_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch.setenv):

```
def test_thing(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('VARNAME', 'var_value')
```

Comment: Ah, but what if you need to do it from a session-scoped fixture, where monkeypatch is not available?

Comment: @MariusGedminas If the var will be set for the entire session you may as well just set it directly with `os.environ["VAR"] = "VAL"` (add in `conftest.py`), not sure what benefit (if any) that using a fixture would provide for a session scoped var.

Comment: Mostly I wasn't sure if assigning to os.environ would also affect os.getenv().  Looks like it does.